# bash script sourcing a bash script located in another directory

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I am trying to source another bash script that lives in another directory using `$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")`. Where `$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")` is currently `/Users/dank/code/<PROJECT>/utils/jwt`.

```
.
|__ utils
    |__ jwt
    |   |__ rand.sh
    |   |__ get_jwt.sh # this sources id/create_new_user.sh
    |
    |__ id
        |__ create_new_user.sh
```

From the project root `.` (`cd /Users/dank/code/<PROJECT>`), I am running `./utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh` (equivalent to `/Users/dank/code/<PROJECT>/utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh`). This bash script sources and calls a function inside `./utils/id/create_new_user.sh` (equivalent to `/Users/dank/code/<PROJECT>/utils/jwt/../id/get_jwt.sh`) since `$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")` is `/Users/dank/code/<PROJECT>/utils/jwt`.

But I am seeing a weird behavior where if I do not source `rand.sh` (from the same directory), I cannot source `id/create_new_user.sh` (from another directory):

```
source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/rand.sh # Why do I have to have this LOC?
source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../id/create_new_user.sh # Does not work without above LOC
```

I get an error if I delete `source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/rand.sh`:

```
./utils/jwt/../id/create_new_user.sh: line 9: ./utils/jwt/create_new_user.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why do I have to source `rand.sh`? Why can't I just source only the script I need?

Comment: if `id` directory is under `jwt` you should remove the `../` part of the path

Comment: @alfasin my mistake. let me edit the file structure.

Comment: I was referring to this line `source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../id/create_new_user.sh` try instead: `source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/id/create_new_user.sh`

Comment: when I `echo $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")`, it's `./utils/jwt` so I figured I need to do a `../`.

Comment: Just tried without the `../`. Got this error: `./utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh: line 17: ./utils/jwt/id/create_new_user.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: You have run it from the folder above utils

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestion: make a copy of rand.sh, and try running that instead. If it works, start removing parts of the rand-copy.sh script and see when it *stops* working -- when it stops working, whatever you just removed was what made it work, and what that is will be a clue to what's going on.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see any reason why you should need rand.sh.

I just tried to replicate your situation, using the following code:

`utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Get jwt'
source $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../id/create_new_user.sh
echo 'All done'
```

`utils/id/create_new_user.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'create new user'
```

Running this using `./utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh` creates the expected output:

```
Get jwt
create new user
All done
```

Sourcing the file in the described manner is valid, your problem must be something else in your script.

Comment: Interesting... In which directory did you run the script?

Comment: I added this to my answer: like you from the project root using `./utils/jwt/get_jwt.sh`